# how to redirect a file into "while read VAR" loop?

Tags: bash

beginner here,

I have the following code

```
while read LINE < $1
do
LAST_LINE=$LINE
done
```

basically, I want to read the file in $1 and extract the last line
but the redirection doesnt work, I've tried to use

```
while read < $1 LINE
```

aswell, doesnt work...

it still wants some input from the user

how to do this correctly?

thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Do it at the end:

```
while read line
do
...
done < "$1"
```

You might also be interested in

```
LAST_LINE=$(tail -1 "$1")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat $1 | while read LINE
do
LAST_LINE=$LINE
done
```

would be a lot more readable in my opinion